# Is there any limit to my power?

Tags: pocket-mortys

Since Pocket Mortys is similar to Pokémon, does it have the same level 100 maximum? Also, is there a limit to how many buffs (+Attack, +Defense, +Speed) I can put on one character? If there isn't, can't you make a nearly immortal Morty?